# Collect all observable strings in array list

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a `map` that contains key/value pair. From this `map` I store them by streaming into a database that returns as a result `Observable<String>`.

My problem comes when I try to reach this string without blocking and put it on the list.

It is always empty. here it is my implementation:

```
public Observable<List<String>> uploadKeys(Map<String, String> entries) {
       final List<String> collection = new ArrayList<>();
       entries.entrySet().stream()
              .forEach(entry -> storeKeysInTheDb(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()).map(element -> element.isEmpty() ? "" : collection.add(element)));
       return Observable.just(collection);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the observable returned by `storeKeysInTheDb()`; until you subscribe, nothing happens and no string results.

```
public Observable<List<String>> uploadKeys(Map<String,String> entries) {
  return Observable.fromIterable( entries.entrySet )
           .flatMap( entry -> storeKeysInTheDb( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() )
           .filter(element -> !element.isEmpty())
           .toList();
}
```

When you subscribe to the resulting observable, the entries will be mapped and stored and the resulting elements will be emitted as a list.